# Fetch JSON File

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, web

I want to fetch a json file (Steam API) and want to show the file ordered in a table. I have tried it with a button and a list but it doesn't work. And i don't know how to do this with a table.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>JSON</title>
</head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("button").click( function() {
        $.getJSON( "json_data.json", function(obj) { 
            $.each(obj, function(key, value) { 
                $("ul").append("<li>"+value.name+"</li>");
            });
        });
    });;
</script>
<body>
    <ul></ul>
    <button>Refresh</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code itself is good! But when you select `$("button")`, the browser hasn't actually got to processing the `button` tag itself yet, so it doesn't exist at that point and the `click` event is not registered.

There are two solutions:

1. Move the `<script>` tags to the end inside the `<body>` tag, in which case the `<button>` will exist by the time the script is parsed.
2. You can keep your `<script>` tag where it is, but wrap the entire script in [jQuery's `$(document).ready()`](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) handler, which executes its callback function when the entire document is parsed and ready to read:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {
           $("button").click( function() {
               $.getJSON( "json_data.json", function(obj) { 
                   $.each(obj, function(key, value) { 
                       $("ul").append("<li>"+value.name+"</li>");
                   });
               });
           });
       });
   </script>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

As your jQuery code is in the `body`, it should go just *before* the `</body>` tag so that all the elements are can be accessed in the DOM. Your current code is running before the `button` or `ul` elements exist.

Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>JSON</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul></ul>
    <button>Refresh</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("button").click(function() {
            $.getJSON("json_data.json", function(obj) { 
                $.each(obj, function(key, value) { 
                    $("ul").append("<li>" + value.name + "</li>");
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: that's what the document ready function is made for: `$(function() { /* DOM loaded for all the code here */});`

Comment: @northkildonan that applies if the script is in the `head`. At the end of the body all elements are available in the DOM, so it's not needed.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ah, yes. just saw he didn't have it inside the head at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>JSON</title>
</head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("button").click( function() {
        $.getJSON( "json_data.json", function(obj) { 
            $.each(obj, function(key, value) { 
                $("ul").append("<li>"+value.name+"</li>");
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>
<body>
    <ul></ul>
    <button>Refresh</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Wrapping your JS with `$(function() {` - `});` will wait until the DOM is loaded before executing your script.